# Can a static class be imported in C# as in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, using, import

Is there a way to "Import" a static class in C# such as **System.Math**?

I have included a comparison.

```
Imports System.Math

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim x As Double = Cos(3.14) ''This works
    End Sub

End Module
```

Vs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Math; //Cannot import a class like a namespace

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double x = Math.Cos(3.14);
            double y = Cos(3.14); //Cos does not exist in current context
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't a way to do that in C#. I also [would like to have something like it](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2009/09/c-static-classes-are-not-real-classes.html).

Comment: As of C# 6, [the answer is now YES](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777014/199364).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As of C# 6, [the answer is now YES](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777014/199364).

---

No, in C# you can only import namespaces, not classes.

However, you can give it a shorter alias:

```
using M = System.Math;
```

Now you can use the alias instead of the class name:

```
double y = M.Cos(3.14);
```

Be careful how you use it, though. Most of the time the code is more readable with a descriptive name like `Math` rather than a cryptic `M`.

---

Another use for this is to import a single class from a namespace, for example to avoid conflicts between class names:

```
using StringBuilder = System.Text.StringBuilder;
```

Now only the `StringBuilder` class from the `System.Text` namespace is directly available.

Answer (score 9):

An updated answer to this question is **YES** as of C# 6.0, which provides a `using static` feature.  So, for instance, `using static System.Math;` allows the static members of `System.Math` to be accessed without future qualification of the `Math` class.

Related SO answers:
[Can Math references be shortened in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11107710/3546415)
[How do I use the C#6 “Using static” feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31852390/3546415)

External References:
[GitHub - New Language Features in C# 6](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6)
[Intellitect - Static Using Statement in C# 6.0](http://intellitect.com/static-using-statement-in-c-6-0/)

Answer (score 5):

There isn't. You need to explicitly invoke methods as features of classes in C#.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking maybe some form of extension methods? This could be tweaked of course.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double x = Math.Cos(3.14);
            double y = 3.14;
            Console.WriteLine(y.Cos());
        }
    }

    public static class Extension
    {
        public static double Cos(this double d)
        {
            return Math.Cos(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with C# version 6, static classes can be imported by the following syntax.

```
using static System.Console;
```